# When ServiceStack authentication fails, do not redirect?

Tags: .net, authentication, servicestack

We're building a ServiceStack API which will use Basic authentication. I've currently set up the auth in my AppHost as follows:

```
var authDb = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory("Server=(...);", true, MySqlDialectProvider.Instance);

var authRepo = new OrmLiteAuthRepository(authDb);
authRepo.CreateMissingTables();
container.Register<ICacheClient>(c => new MemoryCacheClient());
container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(c => authRepo);

Plugins.Add(
    new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(), new IAuthProvider[] { new BasicAuthProvider() })
);
```

When doing a request with no Authorization header or the wrong username+pass the response is a redirect to  /Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=...

Parital request + response example:

```
POST http://localhost:60278/reserve HTTP/1.1

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: /Account/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2freserve
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/3,924 Win32NT/.NET
```

Is there a way to make it respond with only a HTTP 401 Unauthorized or a HTTP 403 Forbidden ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By default ServiceStack's AuthFeature will only try to redirect you to the default `~/login` path for **HTML** Content-Type requests. You can override this by setting the redirect path in the AuthFeature to null:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(...) { HtmlRedirect = null });
```

This will fall back to the standard `401 UnAuthorized` Response that the other Content-Types get.

After globally setting the HtmlRedirect to null, you can add it back on an adhoc basis, e.g:

```
[Authenticate(HtmlRedirect="~/path/to/redirect/to")]
```

Comment: I think there must be some ASP.net stuff confusing me here. I've seen it in the docs and tried the HtmlRedirect=null and besides I'm using application/json for Accept / Content-type headers. The redirect is not the same as you write (~/login), but /Account/Login.aspx. I will go through my global.aspx and stuff, let you know.

I'm accepting your answer now, though, it's the solution when SS is set up correctly. Thank you! :)

Comment: Yes, this was my bad. I still had the .net Membership stuff in my Web.config, seems it overrides the SS authentication. Works like a charm after I removed it.

Comment: I cannot get this to work, I was trying setting it to null, to other paths and I tried both options (when creating new AuthFeature and within the [Authenticate(HtmlRedirect=..)] attribute. It still redirects to login?... If you happen to know what's going on, please let me know, in the meantime I will proceed with debugging against the SS source code.

Comment: Check if your web.config file has an authentication property. That could be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

If the following doesn't work:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(...) { HtmlRedirect = null });
```

Try setting the `OverrideHtmlRedirect = false` to the provider. This works for the `NetCoreIdentityAuthProvider`- especially for JWT bearer authentication

```
Plugins.Add(
  new AuthFeature(..., 
  new CustomAuthProvider(AppSettings) { OverrideHtmlRedirect = false }
) { HtmlRedirect = null });
```

If all else fails, check the Github code to see if there's an html redirect being forced