# ServiceStack authentication with MVC Controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, servicestack

I've followed the samples in SocialBootstrapAPi for ServiceStack but I don't get it how the redirects are wired up. When I go to the Secured controller being unauthenticated I get redirected back to the index page. I was unable to replicate the behaviour in my own application. Did not find where this wirings are done - can't find them in SocialBootstrapApi's web.config?

I've inherited from the `ServiceStackController<AuthUserSession>` and put `[Authenticate]` on my base controller. This is the error I get:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.SessionExtensions.SessionAs(ICacheClient cache, IHttpRequest httpReq, IHttpResponse httpRes) +90
   ServiceStack.Mvc.ServiceStackController.SessionAs() +64
   ServiceStack.Mvc.ServiceStackController`1.get_UserSession() +36
   ServiceStack.Mvc.ServiceStackController`1.get_AuthSession() +5
   ServiceStack.Mvc.ExecuteServiceStackFiltersAttribute.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) +97
```

This is what I have in the AppHost.cs file:

```
        //Enable Authentication
        ConfigureAuth(container);

        //Register In-Memory Cache provider. 
        //For Distributed Cache Providers Use: PooledRedisClientManager, BasicRedisClientManager or see: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching
        container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
        container.Register<ISessionFactory>(c => 
            new SessionFactory(c.Resolve<ICacheClient>()));
```

ConfigureAuth() is similar to the SocialBootstrapApi sample (not exactly the same but close) - I don't think there's something missing here.

So how does this work?

Comment: Did you set your IoC for your MVC controller? `ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new FunqControllerFactory(container));` ?

Comment: Thanks I removed this line when first started to modify the default AppHost, now I've reintroduced it and it works. You can post this as the answer.

Comment: So the answer is actually two part, fixing the session and using CustomAuthenticationMvc project for reference on how to implement redirections.

Comment: ok, promoted to an answer.  Of course you can accept Mythz answer if it's more on-topic for what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Promoting comment to an answer, per OPs request:

Did you set your IoC for your MVC controller? `ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new FunqControllerFactory(container));`

Answer (score 2):

Look at this question to see how to [change the HtmlRedirect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13073251/85785) used by ServiceStack's Authentication.

You may also find the [CustomAuthenticationMvc](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/tree/master/CustomAuthenticationMvc) project in ServiceStack UseCases more useful since it only focuses on Authentication in MVC.

Comment: Thank for the reference to this project, wasn't aware of it.