# ServiceStack service is getting redirected to MVC forms login page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, servicestack

I've writing some tests on ServiceStack services that require authentication using a custom CredentialAuthenticationProvider.

If I create a test by not authenticating with servicestack, I get a serialization error instead of a 401 error.  Serialization error is because the service is redirecting to the MVC login HTML page.

How can I prevent a redirect to MVC when the call is on the /api/ path for serviceStack services so that the service returns a 401 instead?

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void DeleteUser_not_authenticated()
    {
        var client = new JsonServiceClient(STR_APIURL);
        var resp1 = client.Post(new Auth() { UserName = "user", Password = "***" });
        Assert.IsTrue(resp1.UserName == "user");
        var user = client.Get(new GetSupportUser { Email = "test@gmail.com" });
        client.Post(new Auth { provider = "logout" });
        try
        {
            var resp = client.Delete(user);

        }
        catch (HttpException e)
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(e.GetHttpCode() == 401);
        }
    }
```

**Edit**

Per Mythz suggestion, I tried this in global.aspx, but this didn't stop the redirect:

```
    protected void Application_EndRequest(object src, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceStack.MiniProfiler.Profiler.Stop();

        var ctx = (HttpApplication)src;
        if (ctx.Request.Path.Contains("/api/"))
            ctx.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed @mythz answer to the Begin_Request instead of End_Request and it is now preventing redirect to forms authentication and returning 401 response.

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object src, EventArgs e)
    {
        var ctx = (HttpApplication) src;
        var suppressForPath =ctx.Request.Path.StartsWith("/api");
        ctx.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = suppressForPath;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .NET 4.5, you can disable built-in authentication redirect 
by setting `HttpResponse.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect=true` which you can add in your Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ctx = (HttpApplication)sender;
    var suppressForPath = ctx.Request.PathInfo.StartsWith("/api");
    ctx.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = suppressForPath;
}
```

For earlier versions of ASP.NET see ServiceStacks docs on [Form Hijacking Prevention](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Form-Hijacking-Prevention) for registering a custom `SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirectModule` IHtptModule to prevent this.

Comment: I can't do that since I have an MVC front-end that is using the forms authentication.  This answer I think is close, but it relates to calls from AJAX http://stackoverflow.com/a/13811295/4621260.

Comment: I might be able to get your suggestion to work if I check the request for /api* in the path.

Comment: I tried this as you were answering (see my edit).  It didn't stop the redirect.