# Unable to disable redirect in ServiceStack when authentication fails

Tags: servicestack

I am running ServiceStack 3.9.37 on Mono. I only use it as a webservice (no views etc).

I have a custom auth provider.

When authentication fails due to invalid credentials, ServiceStack redirects the response to login.aspx.

The authentication is configured like so

```
this.Plugins.Add(
  new AuthFeature(
    () => new AuthUserSession(),
    new IAuthProvider[] {
      new UserProfileCredentialsAuthProvider(),
      new AdminUserCredentialsAuthProvider()
    }
  )
  {
    ServiceRoutes = new Dictionary<Type, string[]> {
      { typeof(AuthService), new[]{"/auth", "/auth/{provider}"} }
    },
    HtmlRedirect = null
  }
);
```

This is basically the same question as [When ServiceStack authentication fails, do not redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13065289/1256751) but I am running on Mono and do not have any Membership stuff at all.

EDIT:

Forgot to mention that I am calling my service using the Chrome extension "Simple REST client", and I am using application/json as Accept and text/json as Content-Type.

Comment: I have the same issue - did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: No. For the time being we detect failed login by inspecting the error properties on the response.

Comment: Hi - I asked on the ServiceStack forum and they said its a bug.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15654994/servicestack-basic-authentication-htmlredirect-is-not-respected-by-mvc-servicest