# ServiceStack Basic Authentication HtmlRedirect is not respected by MVC ServiceStackController

Tags: servicestack, basic-authentication

I'm probably not understanding something but I have the issue below:

**AppHost.cs**

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
            () => new AuthUserSession(),
            new IAuthProvider[] { new BasicAuthProvider() }) { HtmlRedirect = null });
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
[Authenticate]
public class HomeController : ServiceStackController
```

**The issue**

The issue is that when I try to access the HomeController, I am redirected to `~/login?redirect=....`.

I would assume that by setting `HtmlRedirect` to null, would also affect the MVC controllers too, but it doesn't seem to.

**Is this expected behaviour? or is am I doing something wrong?**

My end goal is to have the browser prompt with a challenge / response basic auth box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/179c4ed2aceef75a1075cf887ae6511f184d3dd0) you are able to override the default behavior when authentication failed:

```
[Authenticate]
public class HomeController : ServiceStackController
{
    public override ActionResult AuthenticationErrorResult
    {
        get
        {
            //return 401 Unauthorized for example
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(401);
        }
    }
}
```

`ServiceStackController.AuthorizationErrorResult` can be modified in the same way.

Setting `HtmlRedirect` to `null` doesn't work in this case, because the behavior of the `[Authenticate]` attribute (and all other ServiceStack attributes) is slightly different when used with ASP.net MVC controllers instead of ServiceStack services.

Answer (score 1):

I have been on the `ServiceStack` Jabbr chat page and was told that this is a bug and a fix will be put on today!

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.FluentValidation.Mvc3/Mvc/ExecuteServiceStackFiltersAttribute.cs#L25