# ServiceStack redirection when inheriting from ServiceStackController

Tags: asp.net-mvc, servicestack

As per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065289/when-servicestack-authentication-fails-do-not-redirect), there's a way to change redirect URL for ServiceStack auth services.

However, when inheriting my controllers from `ServiceStackController<AuthUserService>` this obviously doesn't work because ServiceStackController hardcodes the redirect URL and changing this in `AuthFeature` registration has no effect on it.

My questions are:

1) what is the correct way to go around this problem?

There is an option to override `LoginRedirectUrl`, is this it? What's the point of the Authenticate attribute's `HtmlRedirect` property or the AuthFeature's one?

2) And what is the purpose of `ServiceStackController` altogether?

3) I have put `[Authenticate]` on my base controller and the `[Authenticate]` attribute seems to ignore the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute that I put on the `Login` actions of the account controller.

I know those two are completely separate and `[AllowAnonymous]` coming from System.Web but is there an "allow" attribute in ServiceStack?

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are using ServcieStack alongside an ASP.NET MVC application...

**1) what is the correct way to go around this problem?**

In my MVC Controller that inherits from ServiceStackController I added this for handling redirects.

```
public override ActionResult AuthenticationErrorResult
{
    get
    {
        if (this.AuthSession == null || this.AuthSession.IsAuthenticated == false)
        {
            return Redirect("~/Home/Login");
        }
        return base.AuthenticationErrorResult;
    }
}
```

**What's the point of the Authenticate attribute's HtmlRedirect property or the AuthFeature's one**
I'm pretty sure the `HtmlRedirect` works as expected when not making requests to MVC controllers (ie. calling /api/foo, assuming ServiceStack's custompath is '/api'). I think there are some issues with MVC 'hijacking the return'.

**2) And what is the purpose of ServiceStackController altogether?**
My understanding is that it's main purpose is to [share Session data](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions#typed-sessions-in-mvc) between ServiceStack and MVC

**but is there an "allow" attribute in ServiceStack?**
Not that I am aware of but since [Authenticate is just a filter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Filter-attributes) you could probably create a subclass of it and add some type of support for 'allow'.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's new, but looked at the code and it is actually just optional third parameter of AuthFeature constructor, so you can just:

```
//htmlRedirect is optional 3rd param of AuthFeature constructor, here passing "~/signin"
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
    new IAuthProvider[] { new CredentialsAuthProvider(), },
    "~/signin"));
```