# Register custom credentials auth provider in ServiceStack

Tags: c#, servicestack, authorize-attribute

I was reading this [from their documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization#custom-authentication-and-authorization) which says:

> Then you need to register your custom credentials auth provider:

```
  //Register all Authentication methods you want to enable for this web app.
  Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
      new IAuthProvider[] {
    new CustomCredentialsAuthProvider(), //HTML Form post of UserName/Password credentials
      }
  ));
```

My question is:  **Where do I put this?  Also, what is meant by the comment, "HTML Form post of UserName/Password credentials?"**

Currently, I have a ServiceStack service which returns JSON when called.  I want to add an Authorize attribute above it so that only authorized users will be able to access it.

I have created a class as they suggest:

```
public class CustomCredentialsAuthProvider : CredentialsAuthProvider
{
    public override bool TryAuthenticate(IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
    {
        //Add here your custom auth logic (database calls etc)
        //Return true if credentials are valid, otherwise false
        return false;
    }

    public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, IOAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
    {
        //Fill the IAuthSession with data which you want to retrieve in the app eg:
        session.FirstName = "some_firstname_from_db";
        //...

        //Important: You need to save the session!
        authService.SaveSession(session, SessionExpiry);
    }
}
```

How can I "register your custom credentials auth provider?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You register your plugins within the `Configure` method of your `AppHost`. The comment was just used in the [example](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization) that you pulled the code from to suggest that the `CustomCredentialsAuthProvider` would work with a HTTP POST from a form.

```
public class MyApphost : AppHostHttpListenerBase
{
    public MyApphost() : base("Service Name", typeof(MyApphost).Assembly) {}

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
            () => new AuthUserSession(),
            new IAuthProvider[] { new CustomCredentialsAuthProvider()}
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I use the `[Authenticate]` attribute atop my `public class LocationService : ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Service`, it just says, "Handler for Request not found:"  Is there something I am missing?

Comment: By default users are redirected to `~/login` when authentication fails. If you do not have something setup for this route you'll get that error. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065289/when-servicestack-authentication-fails-do-not-redirect) for a bit more information.

Comment: I set `TryAuthenticate` to `return true` so should it let it through?  (Thanks for the link, btw.)

Comment: Do I have to send an auhorization header or something?  Not sure how to test this properly.